# COLLECT() causes function to enter infinite loading loop

Tags: neo4j, cypher, collect

In Neo4j I have a set of graphs comprising of seed terms and synonyms appended to those seed terms via relationship `[:SYNONYM_OF]`. I'm writing a function where any node that contains a word matching a synonym of a certain seed term gets returned alongside any relevant synonym(s) listed. My current query is shown below:

```
MATCH (b)-[*]->(z)-[*]->(n),
      (syn)<-[r]->(seed:Seed_Term {name: "valuation"})
WHERE (
  (
    n.name CONTAINS toLower(syn.name)
    OR n.content CONTAINS toLower(syn.name)
  )
  OR (
    n.name CONTAINS toUpper(syn.name)
    OR n.content CONTAINS toUpper(syn.name)
  )
)
AND (b:Label)
AND (n:Title OR n:Text OR n:Column OR n:RowName OR n:Cell)
AND (z:Pdf)
RETURN n.name AS node,
       syn.name AS synonym_found,
       seed.name AS seed_term,
       b.labelName AS company,
       z.year AS year,
       r AS rel_type
LIMIT 1000
```

The only issue with this is that if there are three different synonyms found, it returns the row containing the content (node) three times, with the synonym_found being different each time. I know that I should instead do `collect(syn.name)` rather than `syn.name`, however whenever I do this the code enters an infinite loop to the point that I just have to terminate the query. This occurs even if I write `LIMIT 1` at the end. Why is `collect()` causing this to occur?

Answer (score 0):

Your `MATCH` is a cartesian product combined with (undefined) variable length paths.
This is a very intensive query.

I would split the query into (1) matching the synonyms and then (2) getting addtional information of the node:

```sql
MATCH (seed:Seed_Term {name: "valuation"})-[r]-(syn), (n)
WHERE (n:Title OR n:Text OR n:Column OR n:RowName OR n:Cell)
AND (
  n.name =~ "(?i).*" + syn.name + ".*" // case insensitive regular expression
  OR n.content =~ "(?i).*" + syn.name + ".*"
)
WITH seed, n, r, collect(syn.name) AS synonyms
MATCH (n)<-[*]-(z:Pdf)<-[*]-(b:Label)
RETURN n.name AS node,
       synonyms,
       seed.name AS seed_term,
       b.labelName AS company,
       z.year AS year,
       type(r) AS rel_type
LIMIT 1000
```

I haven't tested this query, but maybe it leads you into the right direction.